# Dart: how to create an empty list as a default parameter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, parameters, default

I have multiple lists that need to be empty by default if nothing is assigned to them.
But I get this error:

```
class Example {
    List<String> myFirstList;
    List<String> mySecondList;

    Example({
        this.myFirstList = [];  // <-- Error: default value must be constant
        this.mySecondList = [];
    });
}
```

But then of course if I make it constant, I can't change it later:

```
Example({
    this.myFirstList = const [];
    this.mySecondList = const [];
});

...

Example().myFirstList.add("foo"); // <-- Error: Unsupported operation: add (because it's constant)
```

I found a way of doing it like this, but how can I do the same with multiple lists:

```
class Example {
    List<String> myFirstList;
    List<String> mySecondList;

    Example({
        List<String> myFirstList;
        List<String> mySecondList;
    }) : myFirstList = myFirstList ?? []; // <-- How can I do this with multiple lists?
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Like this

```
class Example {
    List<String> myFirstList;
    List<String> mySecondList;

    Example({
        List<String>? myFirstList,
        List<String>? mySecondList,
    }) : myFirstList = myFirstList ?? [], 
         mySecondList = mySecondList ?? [];
}
```

If your class is immutable (const constructor and final fields) then you need to use const [] in the initializer expressions.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't think of that myself ;)

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on YoBo's answer (since I can't comment on it)

Note that with null-safety enabled, you will have to add `?` to the fields in the constructor, even if the class member is marked as non-null;

```
class Example {
List<String> myFirstList;
List<String> mySecondList;

Example({
    List<String>? myFirstList,
    List<String>? mySecondList,
}) : myFirstList = myFirstList ?? [], 
     mySecondList = mySecondList ?? [];
}
```

See in the constructor you mark the optional parameters as nullable (as not being specefied in the initialization defaults to null), then the null aware operator `??` in the intitializer section can do it's thing and create an empty list if needed.

Comment: Thanks. Also, if your class is immutable (`const` constructor and `final` fields) then you need to use `const []` in the initializer expressions.